# CefSharp.WinForms.Example.vshost.exe has exited -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'。

Tags: access-violation, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

程序“[523076] CefSharp.WinForms.Example.vshost.exe: 程序跟踪”已退出，返回值为 0 (0x0)。
程序“[523076] CefSharp.WinForms.Example.vshost.exe”已退出，返回值为 -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'。

when i run github cef's CefSharp.WinForms.Example Demo, i click item menu "Load Example Extension",the official extension demo "set_page_color" is running ok,but when i add my custom extension,click the item menu "Load Example Extension",then the Program go wrong,it seizing for several seconds,then broke down and exit for the above message.my custom extension works fine in Google Chrome browser,so what went wrong with this ?

Comment: `CEF` only supports a limited set of `Extension API's` see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions It's likely your extension isn't supported.

Comment: i'm adding a 'Canvas Fingerprint Defender' extension which can alter the browser's Fingerprint infomation,but it runs unnormal in CEF though it works fine in Google Chrome.

Comment: Extension support is very limited,  you'll have to do your own analysis,  my guess is it's using API that isn't implemented.

Comment: You can likely implement the same functionality yourself,  extract the crx file, analyse the JavaScript,  rewrite as normal JavaScript that can be executed in a devtools console then you can run that on page load.